# Plot from mglearn

Tags: python, pdf, plot

How can I save plot from mglearn? I tried this code but it does not work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mglearn
from fpdf import FPDF


f = mglearn.plots.plot_knn_classification(n_neighbors=3)
f.savefig("n_neighbors.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

The error was AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'savefig'. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm going to guess that mglearn uses the matplotlib library for plotting, so you can probably just do `plt.savefig()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the mglearn package uses `matplotlib.pyplot`'s plotting mechanics you can use their saving mechanics, like so.

```py
mglearn.plots.plot_knn_classification(n_neighbors=3)
plt.savefig("n_neighbors.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mglearn.plots

import numpy as np
import mglearn
from fpdf import FPDF

X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()


mglearn.plots.plot_knn_classification(n_neighbors=3)
plt.savefig("n_neighbors.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

This code work.